# DotNet Core ReverseProxy that adds header to request

Tags: .net-core, proxy

It's been a while since I used .Net Core (last version was 3.1) so struggling a bit to get back into it (also want to use .net Core 6).
I need to achieve the following. I basically need a reverse proxy that passes along SOAP messages (so HTTP POST requests) but adds a static header to it.

The proxy itself should be simple according to [this post](https://justsimplycode.com/2020/06/21/configuring-proxy-for-http-client-in-net-core-3-1/). But first off that is using .net Core 3.1 where I'd like to use Core 6, plus I need a bit more control to be able to add the header.
What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Update 1:
[Found the YARP (Yet Another Reverse Proxy?) project](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/getting-started.html#net-6-support). That enables me to setup a proxy with config only. Now I need to figure out how to add something to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, YARP made it pretty easy. It's all config.
Basically you use the default project from [their getting started page](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/getting-started.html).
This results in the following program.cs (for .net core 6):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy()
    .LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"))
;

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapReverseProxy();
app.Run();
```

Be sure to add the Yarp.ReverseProxy package.
Then augment the config to set the header and specify the desired target URL:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "route1": {
        "ClusterId": "cluster1",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "{**catch-all}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          {
            "RequestHeader": "MyNewHeader",
            "Set": "MyNewHeaderValue"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "cluster1": {
        "Destinations": {
          "destination1": {
            "Address": "https://example.com"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation can be found here:
https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/transforms.html